# Using dub to build documentation

Tags: documentation, d, documentation-generation, dub, ddoc

How would I use dub to make DDocs from my source files? There appears to be no default command in dub to do this, and I'd really like to be able to automate this process.

Answer (score 8):

Building docs through `dub` is actually specified through a build type.

Try `dub build --build=docs` or `dub build --build=ddox`.

The former builds 'plain' ddocs, the latter uses dub to fetch [ddox](http://code.dlang.org/packages/ddox) to format your docs.

This is actually  shown in the help, its just well hidden. Take a look at the 'build' section of `dub build -h` (you can use `dub <command> -h` to get detailed help on a specific command).

Comment: As my compiler is GDC, as it turns out, this doesn't work without some additional changes to ``dub.json``. Specifically, you have to add the following: 

    "buildTypes": {
            "docs": {
                "buildOptions": ["syntaxOnly"],
                "dflags": ["-c", "-fdoc", "-fdoc-dir=./docs"]
            }
        }

Comment: Interesting -- you may want to report that upstream to dub, as I think it should generate the proper flags for you.

Comment: The `dub build --build=docs` place the output in the `docs` folder but where does `dub build --build=ddox` place its output?